# Do I need to leave Germany after accepting a fully remote job based in the UK?

Tags: germany, residency, schengen, working, brexit

I currently have a job in Munich with a German company. I am a UK citizen and am claiming residency in Germany under the brexit "Withdrawal Agreement", this allows me to continue to live and work in Germany as it was before brexit happened.

I have just received a job offer for a fully remote job based in London. I would like to stay in Germany after quitting my German job but I am unclear as to whether this is allowed.

Am I allowed to stay living in Germany under my WA residency while working for a British company (and paying tax in the UK) or do I lose my residency and would then be subject to the 90/180 Schengen visitation rules?

I have searched online but this specific circumstance is difficult to get information on.

Any information or links to sources of information would be most greatfully received.

Comment: I am not sure it makes a difference in this case but how long have you been living in Germany? Have you secured the new residence document under the withdrawal agreement? Does it say "*Daueraufenthalt*" on the back?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have lived in Germany for 2 years 4 months. I have an appointment in late february where I will get the document you mentioned. I already have the Fiktionsbescheinigung, which states my right to live in Germany temporarily while I wait for the appointment.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should definitely continue working until you receive your Aufenthaltserlaubniss.  That will be the document which allows you to stay in Germany for long-term.

Typically, such a document is given to expire 1 year after the end of your employment.  If you don't have an end to the employment planned at the time of your appointment, then presumably this erlaubniss will be granted for an extended period of time.  This will allow you to stay in Germany and work for this British company until the expiration of the said document.  At that point, you will be able to check conditions for renewing it.